# Lost email after accepting invitation

Tags: microsoft-outlook

After accepting an invitation in Outlook, I have lost the original email. How do I get it back? I have looked in my sent and in my deleted folders.

Comment: Reason #88948923498234 to be really angry at microsoft.

Answer (score 21):

Go to your Calendar and click on the Appointment. The contents of the original invitation will be under Start/End time fields (depending on your layout and monitor size, they might be squeezed and difficult to spot at first).

For future you can disable automatic deletion by following:

1. Go to File tab.
2. Click Options then Mail.
3. Under Send messages section you will see a checkbox "Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding". Uncheck it.

[image]

Comment: @phil If that solved your problem, please accept the answer (click the tick ) to help others who read this in future.

Comment: This changes nothing. Accepted meetings still get deleted from the inbox. Outlook is such a garbage.